# What is the meaning of J in Apache Jmeter performance testing tool?

Tags: jmeter

I have a strange query; I was unable to figure it out using Google. I user [Jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) very often for performance testing, but I’m not aware that what is the meaning of J in Jmeter tool?

Does anybody know what ‘J’ stands for in Apache Jmeter?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about why a piece of software is named the way it is

Comment: So what do you suggest @KatePaulk, where should I ask this question?

Comment: If not here, could be a good topic for meta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Java**

> The Apache JMeter™ desktop application is open source software, a 100%
>   pure Java application designed to load test functional behavior and
>   measure performance. It was originally designed for testing Web
>   Applications but has since expanded to other test functions.

A lot of Java applications start with a **j**, like [jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/) and it often indicates the application is written in [Java](https://www.java.com/en/).

Comment: I anticipate that you are sure that Jmeter is J(ava) Meter.
Thank you for the answer!

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but based on logic this is the most obvious, since other applications follow the same pattern. If you really want to be 100% sure contact the (lead) developer at their mailinglist http://jmeter.apache.org/mail2.html